# UITableView not loading data the second time

Tags: ios4, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I call reloadData in the viewWillAppear method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

However, the second time my view appears, neither numberOfRowsInSelection nor cellForRowAtIndexPath are called

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure *viewWillAppear:* method gets called the second time?

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same problem and yes, using a breakpoint I have already confirmed that viewWillAppear is called and reloadData executed - but cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called and the table contains stale data.

New information: I tried creating a new class/nib, this time using a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController and implementing the delegate & datasource interfaces manually. This works as expected - cellForRowAtIndexPath is called and the table is updated. There must be something else UITableViewController does for me that I need to implement in my version, but I don't know what it is....

Comment: no way. I have been developing apps for a year now and I can't believe just by switching to UITableViewController solved my problem. unbelievable!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! My issue, anyhow. I had wired up the datasource and controller connections, but hadn't connected the tableView outlet in my class to the table in the UI builder. *smacks forehead*. Mine works now, hope this helps!